# Isotope plugin - output messy until refresh

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm having a hard time making isotope jquery plugin to work.

I have implemented it correctly as per the plugin's page instructions, but now I am in front of a peculiar issue.

Upon page load, I get this result:

[image]

When I reload the page though, the output is fine.

[image]

I am working in Wordpress, but issue happens both with cache active or off. I have tried to move all plugins and script files to the top (header) but issue persists.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: At a random guess, i'd say the images need time to download so that the browser and therefore isotope knows the dimensions for it to re-flow your elements for you. When you refresh, the images are cached and therefore load quicker and dimensions are known. You could try adding the image dimensions to the img tag. Failing that, i'd need to see the an example of it not working in order to debug it, it's not a problem that can be easily diagnosed without seeing it myself

Comment: Indeed adding image dimensions fixed it :)

Comment: Great, glad it worked! Think i've encountered similar issues with masonry/isotope before